# Rounding the numbers in a column in Postgre to the nearest whole number

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Good day.

I have multiple tables filled with information about countries. One of these tables contains a population figure for each country; another contains the percentage of speakers of each language.

We are to take these two numbers and make a column that lists how many speakers there are for each language... basically, we multiply them. This is simple enough. What isn't simple, however, is displaying them in the manner that we're supposed to.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT country.name AS \"country\", 
       city.name AS \"capital\", 
       country_language.language, 
       (country.population * country_language.percentage) AS \"speakers\" 
FROM lab2.country, lab2.country_language, lab2.city 
WHERE country.country_code = country_language.country_code 
AND city.id = country.capital 
AND country_language.is_official = true
ORDER BY country.name, 
        (country_language.percentage * country.population) DESC;
```

This is what the first resulting table cell is filled with:

```
 1190528034.66797
```

And here's what it SHOULD be:

```
 11905280
```

Normally, I'd just make these integers of one flavor or another, and this would solve the problem. But as you see, the numbers I want to round off don't necessarily occur after the decimal point.

What should I do to round these off?

Here's my website (it's query 5 that you want to select):

http://babbage.cs.missouri.edu/~asm3kf/cs3380/lab2/lab2.php

and here's the page we're supposed to match:

http://babbage.cs.missouri.edu/~klaricm/cs3380/lab2/lab2.php

You'll see that the inconsistency goes through the entire table.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I updated the site to include the population and percentage numbers. Hopefully, that helps in some way.

Comment: using a ceil/floor/round might help, although, the expected result is 2 orders of magnitude smaller than the actual, is that right or are you missing some numbers?

Comment: It looks like your `country_language.percentage` is saved as a percentage ie. `75%`, instead of the decimal ie. `.75`. So your first step would be to convert those, and then use [`round()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-math.html)

Comment: Sean, 

The percentage numbers are stored as real numbers, according to the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just round the equation result?

```
round(country.population * country_language.percentage) AS \"speakers\"
```

To add the required change to accomodate the percentage format:

```
round(country.population * (country_language.percentage / 100)) AS \"speakers\"
```

The division MIGHT truncate/round the result for you anyway, I don't have PostgreSQL at hand to test.

Comment: Good eye, I didn't think to do the conversion on the actual percentage! 

There's a reason I'm doing the major with less math...:P